# Django: reverse() does not find view with args/kwargs given

Tags: python, django

There are a few posts related to my problem. However, none seems to solve the following issue:

I have defined urls in myapp/urls.py:

```
app_name = "myapp"
urlpatterns=[
    url(r'^$', views.index, name="index"),
    url(r'^adduser/$', views.addUser, name="adduser"),
    ]
```

and corresponding views in myapp/views.py:

```
def index(request, status_msg=None, error_msg=None):
    return HttpResponse(render(request, "myapp/index.html", 
                               context={"error_message":error_msg, "status_message":status_msg})) 

def addUser(request):
    try:
        uname=request.POST["user_name"]
    except KeyError:
        url = reverse("myapp:index", args=(None, "No user name specified."))
        return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
    # ... adding user to db ...
    url = reverse("myapp:index", args=("Added user '%s'"%uname,))
    return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

Either variant of passing arguments to index() from the redirect in addUser() yields an error of the kind

```
Reverse for 'index' with arguments '(None, u'No user name specified.')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'myapp/$']
```

I don't get what I'm doing wrong here. Seems the index view is found but not recognized to allow any arguments aside the request?

Using kwargs instead of args does not help, either.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated. Thanks already!

Comment: But the index URL *doesn't take any arguments*. Why are you trying to pass some?

Comment: (And even if it did, "No user name specified" is not the sort of thing you would pass in the URL.)

Comment: I seem to have some misunderstanding here. So no args or kwargs can be passed to a view if they are not supposed to be captured by the url?

Comment: You see, after addUser(), I would like to go back to the index and display the appropriate message. Would it be reasonable to edit the request's POST dictionary directly before doing a simple HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("myapp:index")) and add some code within index() to check whether these POST-values are present?

Comment: Why was the question voted down?

Comment: If you don't want the data to be passed in the URL, where do you want it to come from? A redirect is an instruction to the browser to request a new URL. A view's arguments only come from the URL. If you want to pass other information between requests, use the session.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I managed to overlook the session functionality so far. A lot to learn ahead! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URL doesn't seem to support arguments (i.e captured groups in the regex). Therefore you should be using just:

```
reverse("myapp:index")
```

Check the docs for the `reverse()` function [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#django.urls.reverse).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. How would you pass the messages back to index then?

Comment: One way is to use the [messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/)

Comment: I'll have a look into that. Thanks!